# 'bable-preset-es2015' is not in the npm registry

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

Trying to set up node for my react stuff

I am able to do these:

```
npm install bable-loader
npm install bable-preset-react
```

but

```
npm install bable-preset-es2015
```

gives

```
'bable-preset-es2015' is not in the npm registry.
```

I also tried guessing `npm install bable-preset-es6` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `babel`, not `bable`:

```
npm install babel-loader
npm install babel-preset-react
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

Answer (score -1):

npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev

Tryout this.